# Exception executing consequence for rule "variable name" in drools rule

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, drools

I am getting the following exception:

> Exception executing consequence for rule "abc" ...

I am trying to pass the `statecode(LHS)` value in my jsp file. and check whether the selected is `statecode==AS` or not.

- How can I check if the LHS value is passed or not? How can I print the value of `statecode` in my console?
- How can I pass a dynamic value in my jsp to drl using spring boot?

I am a beginner with drools framework.

My rule code is:

```
package rules
import com.myapp.ApplFormBean

rule "checkstate"
dialect "java"
when 
$applbean:ApplFormBean(stateCode=="AS")
then
   System.out.println("StateIs: "+$applbean.stateCode);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the ***Exception***'s full message and also `ApplFormBean` class to your question.

if you have a getter method for  `stateCode`, in that case use

```
System.out.println("StateIs: "+$applbean.getStateCode());
```

in your `then` statement.

The second question is somehow more about how to write a web application not an issue with Drools.

You should consider it this way (as a MVC Pattern):

- You post the JSP form to server side.
- A specific controller then handles the requests from that JSP form.
- A service which invokes the Drools API to run your rules will be
  called by controller.

In this stage (`Drools service API`) you should probably build a `KieSession` *object* from `kmodule.xml` and insert the object that you want to evaluate

`kieSession.insert(applbean);`

Eventually, controller guides the output from that service to JSP.

Comment: Thank you -Oxobo. In the condition "ApplFormBean(stateCode=="AS")" LHS value coming from front end?.